How to make rotated text fit and make a table... more good-looking?
Newbie with latex trying to create a decent table... and it is not that easy apparently.
The table shown below has two issues that I cannot find a way to fix:

the rotated text on column one does not find. How may I fix that?
the table itself looks a bit plain, and maybe also a little hard to read. How can it be made more good-looking/clearer?


MWE:
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{lccccc|cccc}
                                                                                              &                                & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Powerlaw model} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Exponential model}                                                 \\ \cline{3-10}
                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Size (MB)} & 100                                 & 500                                   & 1024  & 2048  & 100   & 500   & 1024  & 2048  \\ \cline{2-10}
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\parbox{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Lowest}}}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Satoshis}  & 131                                 & 656                                   & 1344  & 2689  & 274   & 1371  & 2808  & 5615  \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Euros}     & 0.021                               & 0.104                                 & 0.212 & 0.425 & 0.043 & 0.217 & 0.444 & 0.887 \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\parbox{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Highest}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Satoshis}  & 391                                 & 1954                                  & 4001  & 8002  & 823   & 4113  & 8423  & 16847 \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Euros}     & 0.062                               & 0.309                                 & 0.632 & 1.264 & 0.130 & 0.650 & 1.331 & 2.662
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Thanks in advance for your kind help.
Best regards

Welcome to TeX.SX! There are different approaches, the easiest might be to increase the row spacing using \arraystretch. Or you could typeset in a smaller font. Or maybe just don't rotate the text. You probably don't want to write just "Stuff" and "Longer" there, so it is hard to tell what your final table should look like.

Thanks!
I've updated the code with the correct labels, hopefully it's a little bit clearer! I want to rotate the text mainly because the table does not fit in the page otherwise, is typesetting it smaller considered a better approach?

I would recommend transposing the table.  By switching from 10 columns to 6, the table becomes narrower.  More importantly, it becomes easier to scan down a column and see how the numbers are changing.  I'm also a big fan of the booktabs package, which recommends ruthlessly removing lines.  Finally, introducing the column types from the siunitx package allows the numbers to align along the decimal point.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=1.3] S[table-format=5.0] S[table-format=1.3]  }\toprule
    & {Size (MB)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Lowest} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Highest} \\
    && {Satoshis} & {Euros} & {Satoshis} & {Euros} \\\midrule
    Powerlaw & 100 & 131 & 0.021 & 391 & 0.062 \\
    Model & 500 & 656 & 0.104 & 1954 & 0.309 \\
    & 1024 & 1344 & 0.212 & 4001 & 0.632 \\
    & 2048 & 2689 & 0.425 & 8002 & 1.264 \\\addlinespace
    Exponential & 100 & 274 & 0.043 & 823 & 0.130 \\
    Model & 500 & 1371 & 0.217 & 4113 & 0.650 \\
    & 1024 & 2808 & 0.444 & 8423 & 1.331 \\
    & 2048 & 5615 & 0.887 & 16847 & 2.662 \\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}



+1. :-) You may want to insert \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6} after the first row to provide some extra visual structure to the header material.

@Mico I thought about that, but decided that the proximity was sufficient in this case, so I could leave out the extra ink.

Wow, that's awesome! The table looks great, and fits without an issue in the page. Thanks a lot!
